# Is possible convert an associative array in indexed array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, chart.js

I have an associative array, and I´m trying use their values, I dond´t have problem with accessing them and I need this values to generate a graphic, but I can´t use them because the data has this structure `{key1: 12.2, key2: 11.2, key3: 21.3}` however the correct structure to generate the graphic is this `[12.2, 11.2, 21.3]`

The array that I´m usig to store the data is the following

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 22.58
        [key2] => 27.91
        [key3] => 31.95
        [key4] => 36.32
        [key5] => 41.73
        [key6] => 45.78
        [key7] => 48.55
        [key8] => 53.48
        [key9] => 47.82
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 20.94
        [key2] => 27.36
        [key3] => 32.12
        [key4] => 36.33
        [key5] => 41.4
        [key6] => 46.58
        [key7] => 48.8
        [key8] => 52.69
        [key9] => 48.9
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [key1] => 20.23
        [key2] => 26.9
        [key3] => 32.39
        [key4] => 36.95
        [key5] => 41.48
        [key6] => 46.41
        [key7] => 48.82
        [key8] => 52.58
        [key9] => 49.42
    )

)
```

So I think that the problem, as I mencioned, is because it is an associative array.

The solution that ocurred to me was to convert the associative array into onse indexed, I try to do it in the following way

```
$indice = array();
$aux = array();
foreach ($arrData as $key => $value) {
  foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
    $indice[$key][$k] = array_push($aux, $v);
  }
}
```

But this results something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 1
            [key2] => 2
            [key3] => 3
            [key4] => 4
            [key5] => 5
            [key6] => 6
            [key7] => 7
            [key8] => 8
            [key9] => 9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 10
            [key2] => 11
            [key3] => 12
            [key4] => 13
            [key5] => 14
            [key6] => 15
            [key7] => 16
            [key8] => 17
            [key9] => 18
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [key1] => 19
            [key2] => 20
            [key3] => 21
            [key4] => 22
            [key5] => 23
            [key6] => 24
            [key7] => 25
            [key8] => 26
            [key9] => 27
        )

)
```

I hope to a achieve an indexed array that retains the same structure as the original array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 22.58
        [1] => 27.91
        [2] => 31.95
        [3] => 36.32
        [4] => 41.73
        [5] => 45.78
        [6] => 48.55
        [7] => 53.48
        [8] => 47.82
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20.94
        [1] => 27.36
        [2] => 32.12
        [3] => 36.33
        [4] => 41.4
        [5] => 46.58
        [6] => 48.8
        [7] => 52.69
        [8] => 48.9
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 20.23
        [1] => 26.9
        [2] => 32.39
        [3] => 36.95
        [4] => 41.48
        [5] => 46.41
        [6] => 48.82
        [7] => 52.58
        [8] => 49.42
    )

  )
```

Is it possible to make an associative array become an indexed one?

Thanks for your responses!!

Comment: `$array = array_values($array);` in the loop

Comment: Hi @tim Can you explain more your response please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$a[0]['key1']=1;
$a[0]['key2']=2;
$a[1]['key1']=3;
$a[1]['key2']=4;

foreach ($a as $b){
    $new[] = array_values($b);
}

print_r($new);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 4
        )

)
```

ref: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: Now understand I was using 2 foreach loops, and I did not understand well the use of the function of array_values ​​(), it works

Comment: @Robert_Rmz the same issue you had last time.

Comment: It is true I had not considered that this situation caused me problems